# Graphics freezes on Acer Aspire 5516

Tags: drivers, compiz, lan

I have a problem with graphics on my aspire 5516.
I use default drivers for lan(atheros) and video(ati radion 1200) cards.
So, graphics freezes when my lan adapter is turn on but the cable isn't connected in Ubuntu 11.04-12.04 with UIs Unity 3D and GNOME(no problem in GNOME classic and Unity 2D).
Also mouse doesn't move too and I can't restart compiz from keyboard.
I can go to text mode and then turn off adapter and restart compiz.

Could someone help me with that? Each answer is appreciated.
PS. I'm sorry about my poor English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

and add this line

```
blacklist atl1c
```

reboot the pc and re-try the same operation that makes your pc freezes.

Comment: The problem was really with local network adapter driver, but only on x86. On Ubuntu x64 network works perfectly